# Handler to close runtime-made form

Tags: vb.net, forms, handler

I know how to make a form at runtime and to add the controls to it and connect them to handlers... What I want to know is how to make the controls inside this form to react with their container form, for example to close it?

To make it more clear, when I want to close the startup-form by a button on it, I just add this code in the required handler:

```
Me.Close()
```

Then, what should I write instead of "Me" to close the runtime-created form?!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Me, you use the variable that references the runtime-created form.

For instance:

```
Dim customform As New Form()
' add some controls here before showing the form
customform.Show()
' when you're done with the form
customform.Close()
```

Comment: Umm.... this wont help as I'm using a separated sub for making and calling the form, so the handler sub should be outside the creator sub, as a result, the form won't accessible out side it. Thank you.

Comment: If that's the case, you can create a member variable in whatever class you're placing these subs in - member variables can be accessed from any sub in their class!

Comment: Ummm... you mean to declare the variable in the class directly, right?!

Comment: If that's what you mean, it works properly and just like what I wanted it to do... I just pulled the form control deceleration to outside the sub and kept the other controls inside the sub... Thank you for the help :-)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant - glad I could help!